# remove controller name from url in codeigniter with routes

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, url-rewriting

I know this has been asked a bunch of times, but I can't make it work at all. I'm trying to remove the index.php and the controller name (I only have one controller) from the URL.

So far, I was able to remove the index.php, but I still can't remove the controller name

Here is my htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|static|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Here is the top part of my config file:

```
<?php  if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

$config['base_url'] = '/main/';

$config['index_page'] = '';
```

And I put this as my last line in my routes file:

```
$routes['([a-z\_]+)$'] = "main/$1";
```

I'm using BlueHost, and the site is an addon domain to that account. Not sure if that makes any difference. But as of now, I was able to remove the index.php, but I want to remove "main" as well.

Any help would be great!
Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

I'm not where I can try this to see if it works, but what if you leave the .htaccess as you have it and use this in your routes file?

```
$routes['(:any)'] = "main/$1";
```

Comment: Tried that... when I go to www.mysite.com/services instead of www.mysite.com/main/services I just get a 404 page not found error

Comment: Dumb question, but your controller is named main, right?  Also, do you have an index() function in main.php?  In other words, if you remove the $routes definition and try accessing the page as /index.php/main/index, does it work?

Comment: Yea, my controller is called main, and the index() function in main.php is just the homepage of the site.

Answer (score 0):

One of the things I see here that you can change are:

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://your-site.com/';
```

And in your routes.php

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'main';
```

Comment: I have the default controller set in my routes file. The reason I have the base url set up that way is because i'm using the url helper for relative paths when I was working on my local machine, once I switched it live i just removed the base url so the relative paths would all be the same

Comment: Don't mind the comment above. I had to wait for 5 minutes to save the edits, so I'd rather add another comment:
I am using bluehost too and my .htaccess for one of the CI sites is like this: http://pastebin.com/xc3ASGFB. I haven't done anything similar like you have, but to track down the url you are getting in CI is to do some text logging in class CI_Router and method _set_routing() and class CI_URI method _fetch_uri_string, methods are quite self explaining and you can see what CI is getting as url for every request. Also, the uri_protocol is set to REQUEST_URI.